# prevent networksetup from asking for password

Tags: macos, terminal, proxy, sudo

I am trying to get rid of password when changing proxy with networksetup. I changed permissions to read and write of /private/etc folder and propagated change to subfolders.

I tried this:

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/sbin/networksetup
```

and it says:

```
    `/etc/sudoers is world writable`
no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

Changed permission back to readonly, now it says

```
Unable to change file mode on /usr/sbin/networksetup: Operation not permitted
```

I also tried with `visudo -f /etc/sudoers`, but I don't know how to edit file from here. Can you help me out?

EDIT: after running `visudo -f/etc/sudoers` I get this error. Should I delete the swap file? No additional program is editing sudoers folder

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name "/etc/.sudoers.tmp.swp"
          owned by: mainuser   dated: Sun May  1 16:28:25 2016
         file name: /private/etc/sudoers.tmp
          modified: YES
         user name: mainuser   host name: Mains-MacBook-Pro.local
        process ID: 39284
[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort:
-- More --   dated: Sun May  1 16:23:40 2016

(1) Another program may be editing the same file.
    If this is the case, be careful not to end up with two
    different instances of the same file when making changes.
    Quit, or continue with caution.

(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
    If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r /etc/sudoers.tmp"
    to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
    If you did this already, delete the swap file "/etc/.sudoers.tmp.swp"
    to avoid this message.

Swap file "/etc/.sudoers.tmp.swp" already exists!
[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort:
-- More --
```

EDIT: For future reference, if you edit file manually, make sure to do this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7262040?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Terminal and enter `sudo visudo` to modify the file */etc/sudoers*.

Change the part:

```
## User privilege specification
##
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

to

```
## User privilege specification
##
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
your_username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/networksetup
```

and save the file.

If you don't know *vi*: after entering `sudo visudo` you have to change to *insert mode* by hitting <kbd>i</kbd>. Enter the additional line as indicated above. To leave *insert mode* hit <kbd>esc</kbd>. Then enter <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> and the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to write the modified file to disk and quit vi.

Using `sudo networksetup ...` shouldn't require a password anymore.

Comment: If I open sudoers file in textEdit I indeed see what what you mean. Is it okay to just edit the file manually? (there are some warnings at the top, when I open it). Upon using visudo  command I end up with the code above. Should I delete the swap?

Comment: @sanjihan You should first repair/fix the permissions for etc and all items within (files and folders)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the permissions on /usr/sbin/networksetup on a Mac running El Capitan with default settings.

In order to that you need to disable System Integrity Protection. Do this by rebooting the Mac, holding down Command + R to enter Recovery mode. In Recovery mode click the Utilities menu and select Terminal. In the Terminal run the following command:

csrutil disable ; reboot

Your Mac will reboot into the ordinary OS X system, where it is now possible to change the permissions on /usr/sbin/networksetup.

After you're done with that, follow the same steps to run this command in Recovery mode:

csrutil enable ; reboot

Your system will reboot and System Integrity Protection will be enabled again.

Comment: Though this may solve the file permissions mod problem this is no proper or recommended way to solve the main question.

Comment: @klanomath For anyone running El Capitan or later it seems to me that this is the only way to accomplish what the OP was ultimately trying to achieve. Unless I'm mistaken, editing the sudoers file without first temporarily disabling SIP is an exercise in futility.